# PHP - аргументы функции

Tags: php

Нужно создать функция, в которую можно будет передавать переменной число аргументов по ссылке.

Задача такая: В функцию передаю любое количество числовых аргументов, а функция изменяет их значения например на +5;

Т.е.

```
function W()
{
     for($i = 0; $i < func_num_args(); $i++)
         // Может как то тут можно получить ссылку на куждый аргумент и изменить его значеие?
}
```

Comment: Судя по всему, никак так не сделать. Передавайте массив со значениями по ссылке (значения массива тоже могут быть присвоены по ссылке, если это необходимо).

Comment: А как тогда?

function W(&$arr)
{
     for($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++)
          $arr[i] += 5;
}


$a = 1;
$b = 3;
$c = 5;

W(array($a, $b, $c));

Вы так имели ввиду?

Comment: @Скрыто2

    function increment(&$data) {
        foreach ($data as &$item) {
            $item += 5;
        }
    }
    $data = array(1,5,6,18);
    increment($data);
    var_dump($data);
    // array(4) { [0]=> int(6) [1]=> int(10) [2]=> int(11) [3]=> int(23) }

Comment: передавать в функцию аргументы ссылкой не нужно, а теперь это ещё и ошибка. Ссылка или не ссылка сейчас определяется объявлением функции.

**Замечание:** В вызове функции отсутствует знак ссылки - он есть только в определении функции. Этого достаточно для корректной передачи аргументов по ссылке. Начиная с PHP 5.3.0, вы можете получить предупреждение о том, что передача переменной по ссылке устарела, если используете & в foo(&$a);. Начиная с PHP 5.4.0 передача переменной по ссылке стала невозможна, поэтому использование этого приема приведет к фатальной ошибке.

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы получить доступ к аргументам функции нужно использовать func_get_args.

Вот тут очень подробно написано с примерами:

https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.func-get-args.php

```
 function W() {
     $arg_list = func_get_args();
         foreach ($arg_list as $key => $value) {
             $arg_list[$key] += 5;
         }

     return $arg_list;
 }
```

не заметил, что передаются значения по ссылке, тогда этот код не подойдет

Comment: func_get_args вроде только возвращает значения аргументов, но доступа к ним не имеет, ИМХО

Comment: вы же говорите, что вам нужно изменить значения аргументов на 5. Так вот с помощью func_get_args и можно это сделать